# "Prove $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is integrable." Why [$G_i -g_i = \frac{M_i - m_i}{|M_i m_i|}$]?

Tags: integration, analysis

If $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and 
[$\forall x \in [a, b] \  f(x) \ne 0 \land \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is bounded] 
then prove $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$.

I saw [[Prove the reciprocal of a function is integrable if it is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103545/prove-the-reciprocal-of-a-function-is-integrable-if-it-is-bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103545/prove-the-reciprocal-of-a-function-is-integrable-if-it-is-bounded) but I don't understand if:
\begin{eqnarray} f(x) =  \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & ( x = \frac{1}{4n} ) \\
1 & ( x =\frac{1}{4n+1} ) \\
-\frac{1}{2} & ( x =\frac{1}{4n+2} ) \\
-1 & ( x =\frac{1}{4n+3} ) \\
1 & ( other )
\end{cases} ( n \in \mathbb{N} ) \end{eqnarray}
f(x) is integrable on $[0, 1]$. 
Let $P=\{0=x_0,x_1,...,x_n=1\}$
Let $M_i,m_i,G_i,g_i$ same to above page.
then $M_1=1,m_1=-1,G_1=2,g_1=-2$.
Why does not satisfy [$G_1-g_1 = \frac{M_1 - m_1}{|M_1 m_1|}$]?

**I have proved this probrem in a different way.** Thanks everyone!

Comment: This equation generally fails, but you could reach this by using finer partitions. In your example, you may take a finer partition to avoid the situation that the sup of $f$ and the inf of $g$ [or the conjugate pair] are reached at different $x$. e.g. take $x_1 = 2/(8n+3)$ and $x_2 = 1/(4n-1)$. His method is essentially correct.

Comment: I have prove integrability in a different way. Thank you.