# Riemann Integrability of a function and its reciprocal

Tags: riemann-integration

I was wondering what are the conditions which need to be imposed so that the question given below holds true,

> Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ does this imply that $\frac{1}{f}$ is Riemann integrable?

The condition I can think of is,

1. $f(x)f(y)>0 \forall x,y \in [a,b]$

Comment: If it does hold true, why would you need to impose conditions on $f$???

Comment: Take the zero function on $[a,b]$ to see the statement doesn’t hold true in general.

Comment: I'm sorry my formation of the question is a bit ambiguous, edited.

Comment: At least Some boundedness on $f$ And $f \neq 0$  would be required.

Comment: See the following:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103545/prove-the-reciprocal-of-a-function-is-integrable-if-it-is-bounded

Comment: Most textbooks cover the integrability of reciprocal using the condition that original function is bounded away from $0$ ie there is some constant $k$ such that $|f(x) |>k$ for all $x\in[a, b] $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ can be positive and continuous on $[0,1]$, without $\frac{1}{f}$ being Riemann-integrable over $[0,1]$.
Consider:
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 \exp\left[-n^4\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right] $$
or just 
$$ f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}\text{ over }(0,1).$$

This function is continuous and positive but it is too close to zero in a right neighbourhood of the origin for $\frac{1}{f}$ to be Riemann-integrable.

Comment: I guess you need the additional condition $inf=d>0$?

Comment: @Abhikumbale of course, if $f$ is strictly bounded away from zero this issue cannot occur.

Comment: You need the compactness of the interval! In that case, a positive and continous function has always positive minimum, thus respect the condition I gave in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient condition (but not necessary): there exist two positive constants $\epsilon, M$ such that $\epsilon < f(x) < M $ for every $x \in [a, b]$. We use the Lebesgue-integrability criterion:

*A bounded function $f$ on a compact interval is Riemann-integrable iff the set of discontinuity points, $D_f$, has null measure. *

Under the assumptions we made both $f, 1/f$ are bounded on a compact interval. $D_f$ has null measure by Riemann Integrability of $f$. But $D_{1/f}=D_f$ for bounded-from-below amd positive functions, thus $1/f$ is also Riemann integrable.

If $f$ is not bounded from below but still positive, then the notion of riemann integrability of $1/f$ is not properly defined.. I would say that  a not bounded $f$ is r.i if $\min \{f, n\} $ is integrable with integral $I_n$, and $I_n$ converges to $I$. If this is the case, then we can reason as follows.

One can afford a "few" values closer and closer to zero, but not that much! Precisely, let's call $A_n := \{ 1/n <= f <= 1/(n-1)\} $, $f_n = \max \{f, 1/n\}$, $g_n=1/f_n$. Now $g_n$ is R. I. by the criterion I exposed. To achieve the convergence of $\int g_n $, we can require the convergence of the series
$$ \sum_n n*\mu(A_n)$$
In this case, we have that $|\int g_{j+k} - \int g_k|$ is bounded by the final part of the series (why?), thus convergent to zero for $k \to \infty$.

I wait other people to confirm my rough definition of improper riemann integral!

Comment: Questo commento si autodistruggerà tra poco, ma sappi che qualche divinità potrebbe punirti per aver trascritto Riemann con la lettera minuscola!

Comment: Ahahah me ne sto a casa per un paio di giorni allora

Comment: We don't need to invoke a difficult criterion like Lebesgue's. Usual conditions for integrability like the one based on Darboux sums suffices. If $f$ is bounded away from $0$ and say it's positive then $\sup(1/f)-\inf(1/f)=\dfrac{\sup f - \inf f} {\sup f\inf f} \leq K(\sup f-\inf f)$ for some constant $K$ and we are done with the proof.

Comment: Ok, but what about the second part?