# If $f(x) > 0$ and Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ is $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

**Problem**

If $f(x) > 0$ and Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ is $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

**My attempt**

One has to show that $$S(P) - s(P) < \epsilon$$
$$S(P) = \sum_{j=1}^NM_j(x_j - x_{j-1})$$
$$S(P) = \sum_{j=1}^Nm_j(x_j - x_{j-1})$$
Now I consider the difference between these two:
$$S(P) - s(p) = \sum_{j=1}^N(M_j-m_{j-1})(x_j - x_{j-1})$$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ on $(0,1]$, $f(0) >0$ as a counterexample. You need the added condition that $1/f$ is bounded. Then this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1103545/148510.

Comment: x would be a counterexample if the assumption was $\ge0$ but it’s equal to zero only at one point so just change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to view the problem. Denote $M_j^f=\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$ and $m_j^f=\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$. Define $g(x):=\frac{1}{f(x)}$. Then it follows that $M_j^g=\frac{1}{m_j^f}$ and $m_j^g=\frac{1}{M_j^f}$ since $f(x)>0$. That is, assuming there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $m_j^f\geq \alpha >0$ for all $j$. In other words, if $f(x)\geq \alpha >0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition  $P$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\alpha^2 \epsilon$. For that same partition, we have
\begin{align}
U(P,g)-L(P,g)&=\sum_{j=1}^n(M_j^g-m_j^g)(x_j-x_{j-1}) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{m_j^f}-\frac{1}{M_j^f}\right)(x_j-x_{j-1}) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{M_j^f-m_j^f}{M_j^f m_j^f}\right)(x_j-x_{j-1}) \\
&\leq\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{M_j^f-m_j^f}{\alpha^2}\right)(x_j-x_{j-1}) \\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(U(P,f)-L(P,f)) \\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align}
Unfortunately, we cannot assume $f(x)\geq \alpha>0$ so any such counterexample would have to violate this.

Comment: Same as in duplicate.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice.